# Does the chance of serious injury when road biking decrease with speed?

Tags: cycling

When riding a road bike at high speed, for instance in the Tour de France, I have heard that the severity of injuries tend to be decreased as speed increases, as this allows the cyclist to "roll", and somehow this decreases the chance of breaking bones for example. This seems contrary to my basic knowledge of physics and momentum, so, is it true?

Comment: Do you have a source of what you have "heard?" This would be a very interesting read.

Comment: Well actually this was more of an argument with a friend who claimed to have heard it on Tour de France commentary frequently, and when I asked him for a source, the bottom paragraph of this article was the best he came up with: http://www.bikeradar.com/fitness/article/technique-crashing-for-dummies-24316/

Comment: I, for one, would prefer to fall off a stationary bike than one traveling at 35mph.

Comment: I prefer not to fall off at all...

Comment: I, for one, prefer to not fall at all.

Comment: @Criggie Haha, we think alike.

Answer (score 3):

> Does the chance of serious injury when road biking decrease with speed?

**No.** Risk for serious injury increases with increasing speed. If a vehicle crashing at relatively [low speed](http://blackchapman.com/medical-legal-journal/personal-injury-law/low-speed-car-accidents-may-cause-serious-injuries/) has a high risk of serious injury, I cannot imagine how increased speed would yield decreased risk of serious injury.

> The reason slow crashes can sometimes hurt the most is that you don’t have any momentum in your body to roll or spin out of it - instead, you hit the ﬂoor square on and your elbow and hip take all the impact..

Perhaps the cited technique gives you a chance (if any) to avoid serious injury. However, this does not mean that increased speed decreases risk of serious injury.